# Check whether assertions are enabled inside of main function in dart?

Tags: dart

I know that in order to run a file with assertions enabled I must run it with the `--enable-asserts` flag like that:

```dart
dart --enable-asserts file_name.dart
```

How do I verify whether assertions are enabled inside of the main function and print something if they are not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there are any correct way to do this but you can "hack" something together like this:

```
void main() {
  if (assertEnabled()) {
    print('Asserts enabled!');
  } else {
    print('Asserts not enabled!');
  }
}

bool assertEnabled() {
  try {
    assert(false);
    return false;
  } catch (_) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For an approach that doesn't involve throwing and catching `AssertionError`, you can take advantage of the `assert` expression being evaluated only if assertions are enabled:

```dart
void main() {
  if (assertEnabled()) {
    print('Asserts enabled!');
  } else {
    print('Asserts not enabled!');
  }
}

bool assertEnabled() {
  var result = false;
  assert(result = true);
  return result;
}
```

In general, you also can create and invoke an anonymous function to execute arbitrary code only if assertions are enabled:

```dart
assert(() {
  print('Asserts enabled!');
  return true;
}());
```

Comment: Can just use `assert(result = true);` too.